# Show that $f$ is continuous when considered as a function from $\mathbb{R_l}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is "continuous from the right," that is,

$$lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)=f(a)$$

for each $a\in \mathbb{R}$. Show that $f$ is continuous when considered as a function from $\mathbb{R}_l$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

If we show that $lim_{x\to a^-}f(x)=f(a)$ Then we are done but how to solve by mapping from $\mathbb{R}_l$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Where $\mathbb{R}_l$ is the lower limit topology on $\mathbb{R}$

As commented @Brian

> Let $U$ be an open interval in $\mathbb{R}$. We need to prove that $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}_l$. let $x\in f^{-1}(U)$. Then $f(x)\in U$. Since $U$ is an open set so we must have an interval $(a-\delta,a+\delta)$ provided $\delta>0$ there exist $\epsilon>0$ such that $f  ([x,x+\epsilon))\subset (a-\delta,a+\delta)\subset U$. Hence $[x,x+\epsilon)\subset f^{-1}(U)$.

Comment: Explain, please, what you understand under $\mathbb{R_l}$. $l$ is dimensions > 1?

Comment: edited ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Take the preimage of an open interval $(c,d) \subset \mathbb{R}$ and show it is open in $\mathbb{R}_l$.  It just becomes a problem of unpacking the definitions.

Comment: I would encourage you to study this problem geometrically by considering a strictly monotone step function that is continuous from the right but not continuous in general, that is each step is constant on some interval of the form $[a,b)$ with only one of $a,b=\infty$. Now consider an interval on the vertical axis of the form $(a,b)$ where a step occurs. Draw the preimage of that interval using the graph, and see if it is open in the lower limit topology as implied. Then try to work on the full theorem by keeping track of the open sets.

Comment: @Brian See my recent edit.

Comment: @ CyclotomicField - Thanks. It would be really elegant proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea at the end is OK. A slightly more accurate write-up:

If $U$ is open in $\Bbb R$ we need to show that $f^{-1}[U]$ is open in $\Bbb R_l$.
So let $x \in f^{-1}[U]$ and we will show its an interior point of the set.

$f(x) \in U$ and $U$ is open so there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that

$$(f(x)-\varepsilon, f(x)+\varepsilon) \subseteq U$$

Now apply the definition of the right sided limit (at $a=x$ our point of interest), and we find $\delta >0$ such that

$$\forall x': (x < x' < x+\delta) \to |f(x)-f(x')| < \varepsilon$$

And it follows from the previous two facts that $$f[[x,x+\delta)] \subseteq U \text{ or equivalently } [x,x+\delta) \subseteq f^{-1}[U]$$

so that indeed $x$ is an interior point of $f^{-1}[U]$.

Comment: Thanks Professor